# ssh connection stucks when I don't use ForwardX11 variable (-Y)

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

When I try to have a `ssh` connection to a remote machine, its freezes if I don't use ForwardX11 variable as `-Y`. The terminal get freezes and I cannot cancel the operation, I have to close the terminal to exit.

What may be the main reason for this kind of problem?

Can `ssh` automatically try another approach to make new connection attempt or force connnection without using a ForwardX11 variable?

---

My debug outputs:

Attemp that freeze during `ssh` connection:

```
$ ssh -v user@IP

OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alper/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/alper/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.8 [192.168.1.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.8:22 as 'alper'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ukLpqw3yNMx9D29UnmY5rSJRc6Y0ENlAK2R2DNjyljY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.8' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/alper/.ssh/known_hosts:51
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5HDbKAE8ePtTuGB48GSxWzeykOSUKKO5fxG2ub7YTvc
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5HDbKAE8ePtTuGB48GSxWzeykOSUKKO5fxG2ub7YTvc
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5HDbKAE8ePtTuGB48GSxWzeykOSUKKO5fxG2ub7YTvc
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.8 ([192.168.1.8]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/alper/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/alper/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
```

---

Working connection:

```
$ ssh -Yv user@IP
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alper/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/alper/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.8 [192.168.1.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/alper/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.8:22 as 'alper'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ukLpqw3yNMx9D29UnmY5rSJRc6Y0ENlAK2R2DNjyljY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.8' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/alper/.ssh/known_hosts:51
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5HDbKAE8ePtTuGB48GSxWzeykOSUKKO5fxG2ub7YTvc
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5HDbKAE8ePtTuGB48GSxWzeykOSUKKO5fxG2ub7YTvc
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/alper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5HDbKAE8ePtTuGB48GSxWzeykOSUKKO5fxG2ub7YTvc
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.8 ([192.168.1.8]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/alper/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/alper/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.4.20210315-nightly
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Which behavior occurs when you use `-X` instead of `-Y`?

Comment: It connects to remote machine like `-Y` does. Please see its debug log from here: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/401f90fb8f11c64ba3fbba0f1607c0ba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What may be the main reason for this kind of problem?

Most likely there is something in your ~/.bashrc, or ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.profile, that is trying to run an X11-based program. It might be some code you have added for local logins, without properly checking whether $DISPLAY is set.

> Can ssh automatically try another approach to make new connection attempt or force connnection without using a ForwardX11 variable?

No. As far as ssh knows, the connection is **successful** – the server has accepted the channel request and everything. It's just that the remote side just isn't sending you any text, but there's nothing technically wrong with that, just like there's nothing wrong with e.g. recording a video in pitch black.

Comment: My `DISPLAY` value is set to `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.M9XnXH76vx/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`, not sure what set it.  I am using `zsh` shell, but there is nothing that sets `DISPLAY` value in `~/.zshrc`, or `~/.zshnenv`, or `.profile`.

Comment: something in your `~/.bashrc`, ... does it on the remote machine that I want to login or the machine that I am trying to ssh from?